# Why Zephyr RTOS from Linux Foundation uses Apache license?

Tags: zephyr-rtos

Zephyr RTOS https://www.zephyrproject.org/ is a Linux Foundation project. And Linux is well-known for its GPL license. Why then Zephyr RTOS uses Apache 2 license? (How does it affect adopters/users of this new OS?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zephyr uses the Apache v2 instead of the GPL for several reasons, among them those 2:

- Contrary to the Linux case, applications in Zephyr link directly against the OS. That means that every single application would have to be open source if Zephyr used the GPL. This is obviously not acceptable if the RTOS is to be adopted by companies to develop products
- The Apache v2 protects the users of an open source project against potential patent litigation, something that is important for potential Zephyr users that want to be sure they cannot be sued by shipping a product based on Zephyr